# Selenium - WebDriverTimeoutException: script timeout when using Chrome 76.0.3809.100

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I use the below waitTillPageLoad method for any click event so that the next step does not fail. This works for the first few events but throws an exception in line

```cs
wait.Until(
    wd => js.ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").ToString() == "complete").
<package id="Selenium.Support" version="3.141.0" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="Selenium.WebDriver" version="3.141.0" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver" version="76.0.3809.68" targetFramework="net452" />
```

This was working fine for about two years until last week when my chrome browser was updated to 76.0.3809.100. When I use Firefox, this seems to work. However, our team would like to use Chrome for long term. One of my team member still uses an older chrome/chromedriver version and this is working fine.

```cs
public void waitTillPageLoad()
{
    try
    {
        int waitTime = 45;

        Thread.Sleep(200);
        var js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;

        var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, waitTime));
        wait.Until(wd =>
            js.ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").ToString() == "complete");

        driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(waitTime);
    }
    catch (WebDriverException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Webpage did not load for the specified time " + ex);
    }
}
```

```cs
Webpage did not load for the specified timeOpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException: script timeout
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.100)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.ExecuteScriptCommand(String script, String commandName, Object[] args)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.ExecuteScript(String script, Object[] args)
   at Extensions.GlobalDriver.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<waitTillPageLoad>b__0(IWebDriver wd) in <<FilePath>>:line 345
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.Until[TResult](Func`2 condition)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the new chrome browser version. Try using with the updated chrome driver with new chrome browser version.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the version 76 Chrome update which wasn't fixed even by installing the compatible chromedriver version. I was able to rectify my issue by updating to the latest selenium version. At the time of writing this is 3.141.0. Worked immediately after that change was made.